# Why does this SASS (from Refills / Boubon.io) result in whitespace around the element?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am using the very nice SASS framework, [Boubon.io](http://bourbon.io) from the great folks a thoughtbot.  I'm trying to test out the templates they supply (called [Refills](http://refills.bourbon.io)), which by-in-large makes Bourbon.io a more flexible drop-in replacement for popular frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.org).

Mostly this is all very straight forward to set up, but I'm puzzled by the resulting whitespace that appears around the entire nav bar and footer bar that result from simply copy-pasting in these elements from their Refills template.

[Here is what I get](http://cboettig.github.io/whiskey).  Everything appears to be rendering as it appears in the Refills examples, but I'm puzzled by the whitespace surrounding the header and footer boxes.  A quick inspection with firebug didn't reveal anything obvious to me, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this one.

Apologies for the lack of a more minimal js-fiddle example; but doesn't work when one needs to import these SASS frameworks. Source can be found in this [GitHub gh-pages branch repo](https://github.com/cboettig/whiskey); since Jekyll on GH-pages compiles the SASS on the fly to render the example; I've just dropped all the underlying bourbon.io, neat, and bitters SASS files in there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `body` tag has 8px margin set on it. Get rid of that and you're golden. Make sure you use a `CSS` reset of some sort. This is something Bootstrap does by default, I can't say for Refills though.

Also, as your `footer` is `display: inline-block` you're getting additional margin at the bottom. If you change your `footer` to `display: block` then add a clear fix div at the end of it. The blue background should still be the correct height and remove the extra (invisible) margin at the bottom

Comment: thanks much!  yeah, I thought bourbon.io's "Bitters" SASS acted like a resetm but I guess it's not really a full reset.